Pre launch report crash "could not find Fragment constructor", only when built using Jellyfish, ok with Iguana
If I submit a build to Google play for internal testing, the automated fails the build with the following error :-
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.lifecycle.u: could not find Fragment constructor, this only occurs when build with Android studio Jellyfish, and not the previous version Iguana.
My App does not use fragments.
Any suggestions welcome.
Thanks
Jeff
Build app with Android studio Iguana, and upload to Google play store for internal testing, and pre launch report found no Crashes or ANR's.
Build App with Android Studio Jellyfish, and I get 3 issues detected on testing, one of them being main activity not starting.
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.yy.zz.zz/xx.yy.zz.zz.MainActivity}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.lifecycle.u: could not find Fragment constructor"
The app builds and compiles fine on my MacBook M1, I don't use fragments for UI.
Any ideas on this issue, or how to replicate?
This is my build grade file :-
    buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.9'
        navigation_ver = '2.6.0'
    }
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.1'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}

This is app build grade file:-
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}

android {
    
    namespace 'xxxxx'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxx"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 79
        versionName "1.0.0"
        ksp {
            arg('room.schemaLocation', "$projectDir/schemas")
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
            }
        }
        debug {
            //minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.6"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_19
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_19
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '19'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"

    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.14'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.afreakyelf:Pdf-Viewer:v1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:zip4jandroid:1.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7"
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.3.1'
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0')
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

}


Please post your code and gradle file.

Hello Bob, My code is quite a big project, too large to post here, which grades files should I post?

App gradle file

Just added my app build grade code.

is that complete file?

Looking at the error log from google play the app fails for Generic Small Desktop (x86), and the ABI is x86_64.

Just updated to include app build.

Need to see ProguardFile as well.

Further investigation, I found if I removed the minifyEnabled, this fixed my issue, not sure why though.

minifyEnabled true removes dead code which it thought to be unused code but does not obfuscate or optimize it. In your case it removed the constructor class thinking of it to be unused.

Removed statement minifyEnabled, this fixed issue of pre compliance crash for x86_64 bot testing.
